# Android: How to pass back key to the activity behind

Tags: android, key

All:

Is there a way that can pass back key to the activity behind?(Two activities A,B; B is on top of A; How to let B ignore back key and let A receive back key?)

Thanks a lot!
BR.

Comment: And in my situation, A belongs to package A, B is belongs package B; I can change B's code but not A;
Actually I am trying to implement a block UI that once unwanted AP is opened my apk will pop up and the unwanted AP exits in the backround silently

Answer (score 0):

use StartActivityForResult(Intent, int) if you start Activity B from Activity A.
Then in B: set the result on the Intent through getIntent() and finish() activity B

then override onActivityResult in Activity A to get the value

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! And in my situation, A belongs to package A, B is belongs package B; I can change B's code but not A;
Actually I am trying to implement a block UI that once unwanted AP is opened my apk will pop up and the unwanted AP exits in the backround silently

Answer (score 0):

start activity B with following flags added to that intent.
intent.setflags(INTENT.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
startActivity(intent);

then your back will be the back from your previous activity.
Probably you might exit the app if there are no activities behind A

or another simple solution is,
call finish() after you call startActivity(...) for B in A.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! And in my situation, A belongs to package A, B is belongs package B; I can change B's code but not A;
Actually I am trying to implement a block UI that once unwanted AP is opened my apk will pop up and the unwanted AP exits in the backround silently